# Azure monitor REST API throwing invalid token error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I created a native APP with Client credentials

```
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(CLIENT_ID, "myclientsecret");
            //Future<AuthenticationResult> future = authContext.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", clientCred, null);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = authContext.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", clientCred, null);
```

Authority is:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenetID}/oauth2/authorize/
```

This worked fine and got a access token. Then I tried to access Azure Management REST API by setting this token as Bearer Token. Getting

401 Unauthorized

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/{tenentid}", error="invalid_token", error_description="Could not find identity for access token."
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Another observation is, based on this [create service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) documentation, when we add an app in AD it should show up in IAM --> assignment roles, some how my app is not showing up there. Seems I am missing some critical step.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call Azure Management REST API, the resource should be `https://management.azure.com` in your code, not the `https://graph.microsoft.com` which is for Microsoft Graph API.

> Another observation is, based on this create service principal documentation, when we add an app in AD it should show up in IAM --> assignment roles, some how my app is not showing up there.

When you create an app in AAD, it will not be added to the `Access control (IAM)` of your subscription automatically, you need to add it as a role manually. Navigate to the `Access control (IAM)` in your subscription -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> search for your service principal(AD App) by name and select a role (e.g. `Owner`) -> `Save`.

Comment: "search for your service principal" --> My principal is not showing up there, that is the problem.

Comment: @kosa Could you find the service principal in the enterprise applications(filter with all applications) in AAD in the portal?